# Localização e mapas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Olá, vou trabalhar em uma aplicação que eu terei que trabalhar com localização e mapas, basicamente o usuário vai informar um endereço e vai aparecer para ele locais próximos, então eu queria saber +- o caminho das pedras para isso, eu estava pensando em usar *asp.net mvc* e *EF*, já ouvi falar q talvez para isso seja melhor trabalhar com o *MongoDB* ao invés de *EF*.

Também estive pensando em usar os mapas do Google, para localizar os locais próximos seria +- parecido com aqueles aplicativos de banco que vc informa o seu CEP ou a aplicação pega a sua localização e mostra as agências mais próximas, então eu terei que buscar no banco os locais cadastrados mais próximos e ordená-los, pensei em ter um atributo para latitude e longitude, mas como irei buscar e como farei para saber quais são os mais próximos... existe alguma API espcífica para isso.

Comment: Por favor faça títulos intuitivos e descritivos. Tente ser mais objetivo ao descrever o problema. Tem uma série de duvidas no meio da duvida principal, isto complica pra responder e torna a pergunta muito ampla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Existe a API do Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) que realiza pesquisa por latitude e longitude a partir de um endereço fornecido como fonte de pesquisa.

Exemplo:

```
<script>
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  function codeAddress() {
    // Aqui a API pega o valor de um endereço fornecido num campo chamado 'endereco' em tela.
    var endereco = document.getElementById("endereco").value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': endereco}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        // Aqui o resultado é devolvido dentro do canvas do Google Maps.
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode falhou pelo seguinte motivo: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Se você precisa ter um banco de dados de latitudes e longitudes, uma alternativa livre é [a base do GeoNames](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/), que tem não apenas para o Brasil, mas pra vários países do mundo.